# Magento 2 not passing minimum QTY when adding related products to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, related-products

I'm currently experiencing an issue on Magento 2.2.5.  We have a number of simple products that have a minimum order qty set as 100.

If I view on of these simple products, we'll call this **Product A**. I can see the qty field defaults to 100 and when I add the item to the basket, it adds 100.  This is working correctly.

The issue occurs when I have another product (**Product B**) and **Product B** has **Product A** set against it as a related item.  If I tick the box to add **Product A** to the basket at the same time as **Product B**, it adds both products to the basket but there is an error message on the cart page as it has only added 1 **Product A** instead of 100.

Am I missing a simple setting or is it a bug in Magento?

Thanks

Comment: That looks like a bug. The core function `addProductsByIds` in model `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` doesn't check for `minimumQty`

Answer (score 0):

**This is Magento default bug. I just checked and solved the bug and create a pull request in Git.**

Please check commit: [28b8863](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/19566/commits/28b8863a91b6a0e97f1c0da6da12d84b57b94ff8)

Override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php`

Pass request qty to the `addProduct()` in `addProductsByIds()` function

```
$request = null;
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId, $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
$minimumQty = $stockItem->getMinSaleQty();
if ($minimumQty && $minimumQty > 0) {
    $request = $minimumQty;
}
try {
    $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $allAdded = false;
}
```

**Final `addProductsByIds()` function look like:**

```
public function addProductsByIds($productIds)
{
    $allAvailable = true;
    $allAdded = true;

    if (!empty($productIds)) {
        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
            $productId = (int)$productId;
            if (!$productId) {
                continue;
            }
            $product = $this->_getProduct($productId);
            if ($product->getId() && $product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                $request = null;
                $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId, $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                $minimumQty = $stockItem->getMinSaleQty();
                if ($minimumQty && $minimumQty > 0) {
                    $request = $minimumQty;
                }
                try {
                    $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $allAdded = false;
                }
            } else {
                $allAvailable = false;
            }
        }

        if (!$allAvailable) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("We don't have some of the products you want."));
        }
        if (!$allAdded) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("We don't have as many of some products as you want."));
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```